# Count distinct of date field in sql

Tags: sql, date, count, distinct

I have a table below where we have details about Sales Representative and the date time of Sales made. I would like to understand #days each Sales Rep made a sale

| Sales Rep Name | Date of Sale |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1/2/2022 2:03:32 PM |
| A | 1/2/2022 1:11:42 PM |
| A | 1/30/2022 5:25:53 PM |
| A | 1/30/2022 4:28:20 PM |
| B | 1/5/2022 3:15:22 PM |
| A | 1/12/2022 12:04:44 PM |
| B | 1/15/2022 5:15:43 PM |

Expected result :

| Sales Rep Name | #days sales made |
| --- | --- |
| A | 3 |
| B | 2 |

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the number of days each sales rep made a sale in SQL, you can use the GROUP BY clause along with COUNT and DISTINCT:

```
SELECT SalesRep_Name, COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(Date_of_Sale)) as '#days sales made'
FROM sales_table
GROUP BY SalesRep_Name
```

In this query, we first group the sales table by SalesRep_Name using the GROUP BY clause. We then count the number of unique dates in the Date_of_Sale column using the COUNT(DISTINCT) function. Finally, we select the SalesRep_Name and the count of days as the output.